# How feasible digital radio communications would be?

Tags: radio-communications, radio, transponder

Its been over 100 years since we first flew and we still use analog radio with parasites and "radio effect" which changes your sound.

Why don't we ditch the old system and make a mandate a new law where any aircraft that wishes to fly in a controlled airspace has to be equipped with two digital radio communication systems?

What would the coverage costs be like? Doesn't digital systems require less power and antenna size etc to work which would make it better?

Comment: What is the benefit? Just better audio quality? How do you justify the potential billions in implementation costs for that? How do you justify it to the GA community when analog radios cost $2000+, much more for NAV/COM?

Comment: Also for commercial operators, do they have to have 4 radios now? You can't mandate other countries, so an international flight would need both...

Comment: @RonBeyer I thought it would be a good idea to replace old analogue systems with digital systems that can go out further.

Comment: Further would be a problem though since the limited frequencies. I can talk to Minneapolis center from Green Bay, so I don't think that distance is really an issue currently. Local airports don't need the range because they don't need to talk to aircraft they can't control.

Comment: Digital systems can have data corruption as well, so I don't see how going from analog to digital in this case solves an actual issue

Comment: @RonBeyer what about the costs for airports to operate the radio? How much would an theoriticaly digital telecommunnication system apporximately cost compared to an analogue one?

Comment: What's the actual issue?  I think mose of the "parasites" are just local CTAFs all stepping on each other. Digital radio would be no different.  Too many airports too close together, and planes near them transmit and those airborne signals go very far.

Comment: The cost to do this would be mind blowing, and out of all proportion to any conceivable benefit. Any equipment certified for aviation is absurdly expensive, and this idea would require every radio in every aircraft + ATC facility to be replaced. Plus, during a transition period, somebody (either every ATC or every aircraft) would have to be dual capable. Plus, you'd need frequency spectrum to run both at once during the transition. And all to gain what? Because digital is cool? Bad plan.

Comment: You may be aware that [CPDLC](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cpdlc) is a digital-based communication system between pilots and ATC.

Comment: Actually, the standards are in place and the system was been demonstrated about 15 years ago. The FAA program was NexCom and was based on VDL Mode 3 radio system. Using TDMA access and D8PSK coding, it put 4 digital channels in the bandwidth of the current VHF 25 kHz frequency assignments. Each digital channel could be used for CPDLC datalink or a digital voice channel.  In the end, the benefits didn't justify the costs. The benefits of CPDLC in the current system pulls enough users off the voice channels to keep the system within capacity.

Comment: @Gerry *"4 digital channels in the bandwidth of the current VHF 25 kHz frequency assignments"* ...and now at least Europe is well underway in switching to AM with 8.33 kHz channel spacing, which fits three analog channels into those same 25 kHz, *and* does so without a major equipment redesign, *and* maintains similar audio fidelity to 25 kHz AM in practice while allowing narrower receiver filters which should in principle reduce the noise level slightly thereby improving the S/N ratio. (Modulating from 12 kHz of baseband audio in aviation would likely be beyond useless.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Digital is not always better.  Digital modes have been created for amateur radio use; the amateur radio VHF 2m band (144–148 MHz) is very similar to the VHF aircraft band (108–137 MHz).  I have a radio that uses both FM and a digital mode on the amateur 2m band.  Here are some notable differences between FM and digital:

- When the signals are strong, the sound quality of FM is slightly better because there are no digital artifacts
- When the signals are weak, digital sounds better because there is no static
- When the signals are very weak, FM is definitely better because digital either degenerates into unintelligible loud tones ("sounds like R2D2" is what hams say) or is not decoded at all, but analog signals can still be understood with difficulty
- Only one digital signal should be transmitted at a time on a channel; if two signals are there at the same time, the stronger signal might get through, but more likely neither signal will get through

The reason that old-fashioned AM has been kept for all these years is that if two signals are there at the same time, both signals can be heard and understood (perhaps with difficulty).  This is a significant benefit; a quieter signal, perhaps from an aircraft further away from the airport, has a much better chance of breaking through to be heard on a busy frequency.  FM and digital modes can't offer that benefit.

Digital radios are not intrinsically more capable than analog radios given the same power levels.  Digital radios can use slightly less bandwidth for the same audio quality, packing more channels into a band, but that's not very relevant for aviation.

The antenna size varies by the frequency, regardless of whether the radio is analog or digital: the higher the frequency, the smaller the antenna.  Switching to digital wouldn't make the antennas any smaller, unless the frequency band changes also.  A higher frequency band would make the antennas smaller, but finding a new large frequency band for aviation use worldwide would be very difficult.

Comment: A requirement for a single signal transmitted at any one time is not an inherent property of a digital modulation. TDMA (time division, multiple access) is a well-established method of allowing multiple transmissions to share a single frequency range that really can only be implemented with digital modulation, as it requires transmitting bursts of data in faster than real time, with a waiting period in between bursts. TDMA does however usually require that transmitters cooperate somehow, which could be problematic in an environment where the set of transmitters in range changes continuously.

Comment: @aCVn TDMA, CDMA, and other digital multiplexing schemes aren't practical without something like a mobile phone tower coordinating things, which is why digital two-way radio systems (meaning not mobile phones) don't use such schemes.

Answer (score 0):

A MATTER OF COVERAGE:

Digital radio requires higher emitting frequency using pulse modulation or other techniques

analog modulation requires a carrier which could be of low frequency such as in VHF or better in HF

For instance HF radio communications are used in those areas where VHF radio communications are not available due to their limited signal coverage, HF radio signals propagate through ground waves, that are reflected and /or refracted, so the transmission is not linear and will transmit very far.

So analog transmission may have a much larger coverage